# Как сделать 301 редирект для страниц добавив или убрав последний '/' из url? joomla 3.8

Tags: .htaccess, apache, joomla, apache2, joomla3

Имеется сайт на joomla 3.8 с включенным ЧПУ и перенаправлением.

Все пункты меню имеют адреса вида:

- site.ru/page1
- site.ru/page2

но страницы так же доступны и по адресам с окончанием на /, то есть:

- site.ru/page1/
- site.ru/page2/

Являются ли страницы дублями и как их привести к одному варианту сделав редирект убрав / из конца или добавив его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На просторах интернета http://romanus.ru/301-redirekt-v-seo/ нашел такой ответ:

Убрать / из конца url:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Вставит / в конец:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```